# Free jqGrid 4.9.0 - Reset on multisearch = true delete the selection bar when re-entering the second time

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I placed a demo for the problem at [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tyanai/ngm5rhgp/5/) `$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
                datatype: "local",
                data: mydata,
                height: 250,
                width: 780,
                page: 1,
                colModel: [`

The link point to the latest Free-jqGrid, but I noticed this also at my local 4.9.0 version.

In the Demo, at the bottom left there is a 'search' button that opens a multi search dialog.  So far so good:

[image]

Now, when user click the "Reset & Close" and repeat the operation once again (aka click once again on the bottom left search icon), the dialog that will now open will be missing the default first option line:

[image]

Thanks for the help,

Tal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but the demo which you use includes wrong files. For example you use `ui.jqgrid.css`

```
http://bester.co.il/regression/css/ui.jqgrid.css
```

which seems to be from some old version of jqGrid, but it's sure not the `ui.jqgrid.css` which come from free jqGrid. I don't verified other files which you included and just replaced all URLs from the demo to the sources from CDN or GitHub. The resulting demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/ngm5rhgp/7/ don't have the problems which you describes.

**UPDATED:** Now I realized that that the problem do exist after clicking of Reset button only. The problem exist because of assigning empty string as the value of `filter` in `postData` (see [the line](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.9.2/js/grid.formedit.js#L354) of code). I posted now [the fix](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/fe7d5112e9606626f0d53c98e581b5e5915a04f9) which set `undefined` value instead. Now the problem should be solved. Thank you for reporting of the problem!

Comment: Thanks Oleg.  The resulting demo you referenced, have the exact same problem.   When you reopen the seach dialog for the second time AFTER you closed it on the first time using the "RESET" button, you lose the center of the dialog.

Comment: @Tal: Thank you! I posted the fix. See **UPDATED** part of my answer.